# wpf datagrid vs listbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox

I have been using listboxes in my application. Now I'm considering using datagrids instead. Is there anything that can be done in a `Listbox` that cannot be done in a `Datagrid`?

Comment: @richard-alan-s: `Is there anything that can be done in a LISTBOX that cannot be done in a listbox?`  'No' would be the answer for this. You have to rephrase your question.

Comment: oops. Is there anything that can be done in a LISTBOX that cannot be done in a datagrid. Thanks for the correction :-)

Answer (score 2):

**DataGrids** do some great things like automatically generate columns and headers (**AutoGenerateColumns = "True"**), allow a user to add/edit rows of information easily to the bound items (**UserCanAddRows = "True"**), and many other features.

With a lot of work you could make a **ListView** act just like a **DataGrid**, however a **DataGrid** is very convenient when working with grids of data, such as a database with many columns, and is ready to be bind to your collections via data binding.

In short, it just saves you a lot of work. If you need help with the specifics of working with **DataGrids**, there are many smart folks on StackOverflow that will help you with such specifics :D